# RESTsharp get command with &

Tags: c#, rest, api, restsharp

Hey all this is the first time I am trying out **RESTsharp**. I am trying to create a **GET** call that looks like this:

```
http://labs.bible.org/api/?passage=random&type=json
```

I've tried the following with looking at some online examples:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://labs.bible.org/");
var request = new RestRequest("api/?{0}&{1}", Method.GET);

request.AddParameter("passage", "random");
request.AddParameter("type", "json");

var queryResult = client.Execute<List<quotesAPI>>(request).Data;
```

When I put a stop on the **queryResult** it just says NULL.

**quotesAPI** looks like this:

```
public class qAPI
{
   public string bookname { get; set; }
   public string chapter { get; set; }
   public string verse { get; set; }
   public string text { get; set; }
}
```

So how do I need to format the call in order for it to work as it should be?

**update 1**

```
 var client = new RestClient("http://labs.bible.org/");
 var request = new RestRequest("api", Method.GET);

 request.AddParameter("passage", "random");
 request.AddParameter("type", "json");
 client.AddHandler("application/x-javascript", new RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer());

 var queryResult = client.Execute<List<quotesAPI>>(request).Data;
```

Comment: Create request like this: `new RestRequest("api", Method.GET);`, no need to pass any `{0}&{1}` there.

Comment: @Evk looks like that also comes back **NULL**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is no need to create rest client like this:

```
new RestRequest("api/?{0}&{1}", Method.GET);
```

This will result in query to `http://labs.bible.org/api/?{0}&{1}&passage=random&type=json`. In this specific case it might still "work", but in general you should of course avoid this. Instead, create it like this:

```
new RestRequest("api", Method.GET);
```

For GET methods, parameters you then create will be appended to query string for you.

Another problem here is unusual content type of response. Response for your query has content type `application/x-javascript`. RestSharp has no idea what to do with such content type, so you should tell it:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://labs.bible.org/");
client.AddHandler("application/x-javascript", new RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer());
```

Here you say that it should deserialize response with such content type as json. After that you should receive expected result.

Comment: i get data back but it doesn't go anywhere - as in the values im looking for are not there.

Comment: @StealthRT not sure what you mean, I tested this code and it returns values just fine. Though not sure what is `List<quotesAPI>`, because your class name is `qAPI` in question. I tested with `List<qAPI>` and it returns list with 1 item, with bookname "2 Samuel" and so on.

Comment: That as the issue. Not having the **.qAPI**. Now i see the data like you do. Thanks Evk!